Trying to understand how analyticity forces the given relation.
In this paper, the author  reaches the relation
$$ \left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\right\vert^{-1/2}=e^{\chi(t)}\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{H\Psi}_1^{1/2}\right\vert^{-1/2},\tag 1\label 1$$
where $ \chi(t) = 2t^2(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2)^\top \boldsymbol\Psi_2^{-1}\left(\boldsymbol\Psi_1^{-1}-2t\boldsymbol H\right)^{-1}\boldsymbol\Psi_2^{-1}(\boldsymbol\eta_1-\boldsymbol\eta_2) + c. $
The author then claims in the neighborhood of $t=0$,$$\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{H\Psi}_1^{1/2}\right\vert/\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\right\vert=\exp(2(\chi(t)).\tag 2\label 2$$
He then considers $t$ as a complex variable and claims

because the  both sides of $\eqref 2$ are a single-valued regular function except finite points,

that would imply $\chi(t) \equiv 0$ and thus for all $t$ it holds true that $$\left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Psi}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{H\Psi}_1^{1/2}\right\vert= \left\vert\mathbf I -2t\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\boldsymbol{G\Sigma}_1^{1/2}\right\vert.\tag 3\label 3$$
I couldn't understand how the author concluded $\eqref 3$ from $\eqref 2$.
$\eqref 2$ was reached from $\eqref 1$ for values of $t$ in neighborhood of $t=0.$
How come when $t$ is considered complex, the relation $\eqref 2$ holds for all values of $t$?  I can see the lhs could be analytic but I am failing to see why $\chi(t) \equiv 0.$
My question is: how did the author conclude $\eqref 3$ from $\eqref 2$?
NB. $\boldsymbol\Psi_1\boldsymbol\Psi_1, \boldsymbol\Sigma_2,\boldsymbol\Sigma_2$ are positive definite matrices of order $p; $ $\boldsymbol G= \boldsymbol\Sigma_1^{-1}-\boldsymbol\Sigma_2^{-1}$ and $\boldsymbol H= \boldsymbol\Psi_1^{-1}-\boldsymbol\Psi_2^{-1}.$

The answer to the question in your title is no which is obvious for $g(t)=t$.

I see @StevenClark. Got confused while writing it. I will modify the title properly.

Your third to last paragraph is perhaps also misleading with respect to your specific question.

Thanks again @StevenClark.

There is a mistake in my comment and I correct it in my answer.

$(2) \implies (3)$ is correct, but not for the reason the author claims.
Note that the LHS of $(2)$ is a quotient of determinants, thus a rational function. In contrast, the RHS of $(2)$ is the exponential of the polynomial $\chi(t)$. To have these $2$ functions equal, they must both be some constant $C$. However, the constant terms of the numerator and denominator of the LHS of $(2)$ are both $1$, which forces $C=1$.

Just another side query: author reached $\eqref 2$ for values of $t$ in neighborhood of $t=0$. Why was that needed in the first place (after all, we are seeing it holds for all $t$)?

@User1865345 The LHS of $(2)$ is definable iff the denominator is not $0$. So the author claims the equality only in a neighbourhood of $t=0$.
